# Semi-piano app touch troubles with UIButtons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, touches, piano

I am working on a semi-piano app with a diffrent keyboard-layout then a usual one.

I created the view manually with UIButtons,
My problem was I that I didn't know how to slide from a UIButton to another,
I figured that out with addTarget with the option of withEvent, which gave me the access to the touches.

Now, after I added the target like this:

```
[C addTarget:self action:@selector(outsideOfKey: forEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragOutside|UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
[C addTarget:self action:@selector(keyGetsLeft: forEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside | UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

(also for all of the other keys),

I maneged to make them slideable,

`outsideOfKey:forEvent:` is as follows:

```
-(void) outsideOfKey:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{    
    for(UITouch *t in [event allTouches])
    {

            CGPoint touchPoint = [t locationInView:window];
            if(CGRectContainsPoint(C.frame, touchPoint))
             {
                 C.highlighted = YES;
             }
            else{
                C.highlighted = NO;
            }
```

(Done for all the other keys as well)
I can slide from and into other keys, and when I leave them in `keyGetsLeft:forEvent`: I have just used the same syntx without the else, and the highlighted became NO.

Up to here it's easy,
But then when I try to do multi-touch, I can slide only one of the touches all around and the others must stay in the same position.

And even more, If I take one of the fingers away all of them are becoming non-highlighted, 
I know the reasons to all of that, but I don't know how to fix it and make it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid, [bensnider](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8272190/106435) is right. But I'd implement it via GestureRecognizer:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/handling_uikit_gestures
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer

Each key has one TapRecognizer, while a parent view has a SwipeRecognizer to detect slides form one key to another.

Very useful, on [Apple Developer Video Archive](https://developer.apple.com/videos/archive/)<sub>login with development account required</sub>:

- WWDC2010: Session 120 — Simplifying Touch Event Handling with Gesture Recognizers
- WWDC2010: Session 121 — Advanced Gesture Recognition

Comment: Do you think that I will be able to create a piano-like app with the GestureRecognizer? My main actions are going to be dragging the touch, staying at one point(or with slight movments), and tracking if a finger is moving rapidly from side to side on the same view(or key), I don't think I'd have the access to all that with only the GestureRecognizer. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Also you can define custom Recognizers with similar amount of work as using custom views, but with less inheritance hassle resulting in cleaner code.

Comment: see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW2 for custom recognizers. Actually most of the work is done in method with same signatures as those touches… methods from UIResponder.

Comment: karen view? excuse me, I'm very new to all of this.

Comment: karen view? do u mean custom view? a custom UIView subclass.

Comment: I meant parent view. or superview.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably move away from UIButtons altogether and implement my own custom touch tracking code. See [Handling Multitouch Events](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MultitouchEvents/MultitouchEvents.html) in the docs. Namely, you will be implementing the following methods:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

I would probably just implement hit areas, which you could setup in IB, with perhaps a custom UIView touch overlay (just a UIView with a custom subclass). This would let you setup the view in IB with images, titles, etc., but do all of your touch tracking in your custom subclass.

Comment: the problem is the I need the title and background image features that are in the UIButton, and I'm afraid I'll lose my hands and feet in a new class.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use one view for all buttons and manually implement touch tracking as bensnider said. Manually drawing backgrounds/titles also is not so difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a link to an open source iOS piano app I made https://github.com/meech-ward/iOSPiano

I used CALayers for the piano keys and I used

`- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;`

to detect if the user is currently touching a piano key.
It works really well even with multiple touches.